# Issue in Ionic android app production build - TypeError: compiler_1.isFormattedError is not a function at syntaxErrorToDiagnostics

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, production

Please help me to get this fixed.

I am able to create release build successfully.

But on production build i am getting below error

> [09:37:08]  TypeError: compiler_1.isFormattedError is not a function
>   TypeError: compiler_1.isFormattedError is not a function
>       at syntaxErrorToDiagnostics (D:\Ionicserver\icdl-updated-node-modules\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:943:29)
>       at AngularCompilerProgram._addStructuralDiagnostics (D:\Ionicserver\icdl-updated-node-modules\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:600:37)
>       at AngularCompilerProgram._createProgramOnError (D:\Ionicserver\icdl-updated-node-modules\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:592:22)
>       at Promise.resolve.then.catch.e (D:\Ionicserver\icdl-updated-node-modules\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:189:34)
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

```
    ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Thanks for your time.

Thanks,
Tushar